# PHP: How to call function outside of class

Tags: php, logging

I'm trying to implement a "logger" into a web tool I'm working on, which basically is a php file looking like this:

```
<?php
function makePost($post) {
    $file = fopen("log.txt", "a") or die ("Unable to open file");

    $today = date("Y/m/d-h:i");
    fwrite($file, $today . "\n====================================");

    fwrite("\n" . $post);
    fwrite("\n====================================");

    fclose($file);
}
```

Which I'm trying to call from other locations in the "web tool" and the problem arises when I'm trying to call it from a class which I have in order to handle the database and as I try to call the above function it seems like the program just stops in it's tracks and the rest of the function (and the logger itself) isn't executed.

Simplified class from which I try to call the logger:

```
class handleAccounts {
    function loginValidation() {
        require_once("log.php");
        makePost("A login was attempted");

        // Some more code that isn't executed
    }
}
```

Comment: First do move `require_once("log.php");` outside and above the class. `log.php` defines a global function so include it global.  For the rest: Did you get any error that you can show here?

Comment: you have to first initaillize the class and than call the function.

$a =urclass();
$a->makePost();

Comment: Second `trying to call it from a class` is this class in the same folder as all other files. Currently the `log.txt` is wirtten into that folder where the classfile is not where `log.php` is. Have you permission for that folder? Is that the right folder?

Comment: Last, this line is all you need: `file_put_contents('log.txt',"$today\n".str_repeat("=",20)."\n$post\n".str_repeat("=",20)."\n",FILE_APPEND)` creates or append the data to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your MakePost function on lines 8 and 9. Solved this by commenting lines 8 & 9.

```html
function makePost($post) {
    $file = fopen("log.txt", "a") or die ("Unable to open file");

    $today = date("Y/m/d-h:i");
    fwrite($file, $today . "\n====================================");

//    fwrite("\n" . $post);
//    fwrite("\n====================================");

    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it like this

```
<?php
function makePost($post) {
  $today = date("Y/m/d-h:i");
  $sep = str_repeat‌​("=",20);
  $res = file_put_contents('log.txt',"$today\n$sep\‌​n$post\n$sep\n",FILE_A‌​PPEND);
  if(!$res){
    die ("Unable to open and write to file");
  }
}
```

and

```
<?php
require_once("log.php");
class handleAccounts {
 function loginValidation() {
    makePost("A login was attempted");
    // Some more code that isn't executed
 }
}
```

Note for the `'log.txt'`:
If for example `log.php` is under `/foo/bar/log.php` and the logfile should be under `/foo/log/log.txt` you can do `dirname(__FILE__).'/../log/log.txt'` instead of just `'log.txt'`, so you will always write into the same file in the same folder.